# DatePicker template, borders appear on mouse over

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a weird problem,

My DatePicker shows in the middle some borders. I don't know where it comes from.

I changed every property of the DatePickerTextBox but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the XAML :

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" Margin="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                   BorderThickness="0"
                                   BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                   Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                   Visibility="Visible"
                                   SelectionBrush="#FF6F5DF5" 
                                   FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                                
                                <DatePickerTextBox.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DatePickerTextBox.Style>
                            </DatePickerTextBox>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0.333,0.333" Width="24">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/down.png"></Image>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Margin="0,0,0.333,0.333" />

                            <Label x:Name="lblLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Uid}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderThickness="0" Padding="12,0" FontFamily="Poppins" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,-11,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF6F5DF5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF6F5DF5"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property = "BorderBrush" Value="{Binding ToYourBorder}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<DatePicker Margin="10,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Uid="Date de naissance *" FontSize="12" Height="40" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="181" FontFamily="Poppins" Background="#FFFEFEFE" BorderBrush="#FF9A9A9A" Foreground="#FF727272" />
```

And here how it seems :

[image: The styele]

And on hover, there is another thin border inside :

[image: On mouseover]

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatePickerTextBox has it's own Template where the border and the triggers for the border are defined/hardcoded.

You need to take care of those in the template of DatePickerTextBox.

Change:

```
<DatePickerTextBox.Style>
     <Style>
         <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
     </Style>
</DatePickerTextBox.Style>
```

To:

```
<DatePickerTextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
         <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate>
                          <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" BorderThickness="0"
                                                             Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                     </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
</DatePickerTextBox.Style>
```

And it should work.

For a complete Template see [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)